# struct python format of string dynamicly lenght

Tags: python, python-2.7, struct

I want to use struct and pack a string and a number. 
so I saw the format is '10s' for 10 bytes, 
but how should I write if I want any time other lenth of string? 
and I cant tell it 10. what should I write in the format? 
there is a way to do this dynamic?

```
packed=struct.pack('i10s',1,"abaBaabb");
```

thanks

edit :

if I don't know the size of the packet I get- 
just it is int int and string.. 
how to write the unpack:

```
id, data= struct.unpack_from('is' ,message,0)
```

will get only one char
but if I write:

```
id, data= struct.unpack_from('i500s' ,message,0)
```

because I know it will be until 500 Bytes
it make an error if the string is smaller.

what should I do ?

or- how can I get reed of the following 0\00\00\00\0:

> abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
>   abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
>   \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00

if I get such a string ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to compute format string on the fly:

```
struct.pack("%ss" % 3, "xyz")

foo = "bar"
struct.pack("%ss" % len(foo), foo)
```

Comment: thank you!! how can i get a specific value from the unpack after? myStr='afgf' packed=struct.pack('i%ss' %len(myStr),1,myStr);
print 'packed',packed
print struct.unpack('i%ss' %len(myStr),packed) so I want to get the '1' number for example from the unpacked in a different file

Comment: Either add a header to the message, or compute string size based on message size.